# 404 Error at REST-Webservice example with Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to build a simple java-based REST web-service using JSON. I am also using Maven for dependency management.

Since I am new to this, I have been thoroughly following a nice 5-step-tutorial on http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/, however I don't get this easy example to run.

Maven ran fine, and all necessary dependencies were downloaded and integrated in the project (the libraries are contained in the deployed .war-file). Only problem is, that when I want to open the URL given in the tutorial (localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get) after having deployed the project, I am getting a 404 Error without any additional information.

Edit:

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As I said, the build ran fine and dependencies are loaded and integrated into the project.

Now, here is the content of my web.xml
    Restful Web Application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Next to this, I use a class JSON-Service and a model class Track. My JSON Service looks like this:

```
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to check for server-side exceptions, any hint on this is also kindly appreciated... :-)

Comment: any server side exceptions ??

Comment: I think you have an error in your request, please explain your problem with some sample code....

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` and `pom.xml` in your question ? What is your server application (JBoss?) and its version ?

Comment: Your class JSONService is well placed in the package com.mkyong.rest ?

Answer (score 0):

you defined in your servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so your url should be correctly called `localhost:8080/rest/json/metallica/get`